# Grails UI plugins

Tags: grails

I'm doing web project using Java EE framework.
I want to use Grails UiPerformance plugin in my project.
Can I use that plugin for user interface design?
I would like to know what is the purpose of this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why this is not the plugin you want. The purpose of the plugin is described [here](http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) - it's to improve page loading performance and deals with gzipping, minification, bundling, etc.

The primary reason is that it has nothing to do with interface design. And if you do want a plugin for static resource handling, the [asset-pipeline](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) plugin is the current best option.